# How to turn off "Use Legacy display ICC color management"?

Tags: windows, manifest, compatibility

In Windows under application properties->Compatibility there is a flag to "Use Legacy display ICC color management" which lets apps that are not Advanced Color aware run nicely when Advanced Color is turned on. It's automatically turned on for many apps. I'd like to put something like advancedColorAware in my manifest similar to the switches for longPathAware or ultraHighResolutionScrollingAware so my application can use Advanced Color and not have to tell users to turn off the compatibility flag manually, but can't find such a thing. Microsoft says there's no programmatic way to control this flag (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wcs/advanced-color-icc-profiles) but usually there's a way once your fix your app to mark it compatible with a new feature or version of the OS.

Without changing the flag, all my controls like scrollbars appear washed out when using Advanced Color and the Advanced Color APIs although content drawn with Advanced Color looks correct. Turning off the compatibility flag fixes all the controls.